# How to make a button and colored rectangle side by side on android?

Tags: android, gridview, view, alignment

I am trying to make a button and a colored rectangle side-by-side. I am not sure if I need to do this with linear layouts, grid layouts, or somehow else. Here is what I have tried:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_row="0"
            app:layout_column="0"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_row="1"
            app:layout_column="0"
            android:text="Button" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
            app:layout_column="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            app:layout_row="0" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
            app:layout_column="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            app:layout_row="1" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

This produces the following image: [image]

The top looks correct. I want a thin button with an equally thin rectangle next to it. I could not make the bottom work. What is the most efficient way of doing this, preferably so that new rows can be added programmatically (start at 2 rows and add more).

Comment: try this, change girdlayout height match_parent to wrap_content

Answer (score 0):

Currently, to achieve what you are trying to, here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />


        <View
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />


        <View
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

I would advice using a RecyclerView, in which you could programmatically inflate an item view and bind information to that view. RecyclerView manages all the inflation and addage of new items and all, for you.
You could follow this [tutorial](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/) on setting it up.

You can read up on how to achieve that, and here is what your list item will look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />


        <View
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />

</LinearLayout>
```